# Perl regex replace unexpectedly running twice with "g" option

Tags: regex, perl, bash

So I have a folder with more folders in it. I wanted to tell a friend that they should, instead of having folders each with source files in them, have just the source files each with multiple functions in them;

i.e. instead of this:

```
src/
    load_of_functions/
        function1.py
        function2.py
        function3.py
        function4.py
    load_more_functions/
        function5.py
        function6.py
        function7.py
    even_more_funcitons/
        function9.py
        function10.py
```

that they should have this:

```
src/
    load_of_functions.py
    load_more_functions.py
    even_more_funcitons.py
```

So i went into the directory, and did a litte one liner to get the names of the dirs to put in an email;

```
$ ls -l | grep ^d | awk '{print $9}' | perl -pe 's/(.*)/\1.py/g'
```

`ls -l` to get the files and all the info
`grep ^d` to keep just the dirs
`awk '{print $9}'` to print just the 9th column - i.e. the dir name
and `perl -pe 's/(.*)/\1.py/g'` to add ".py" to each line.

when i do this, i get this:

```
$ ls -l | grep ^d | awk '{print $9}' | perl -pe 's/(.*)/\1.py/g'
1.py.py
10.py.py
2.py.py
3.py.py
4.py.py
5.py.py
6.py.py
7.py.py
8.py.py
9.py.py
```

I get that I'm not parsing a file, but doing it line by line, so the `g` for global isn't needed. So I take that out, and it works fine.

This is fine.

But why does it do the replace twice when i put the `g` in? This makes no sense to me!

Comment: Wow. That's an impressively redundant chain of pipes. `perl -lwe 'for (grep -d, <*>) { print "$_.py"; }'`

Comment: @TLP in typical bash fashion, these are the collection of ways i know to do certain things, so hey why not!

Comment: Well, now you know how to do those things in perl directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.*` matches zero or more characters, which means it can match zero characters.

Let's say you have

```
$_ = 'abc';
s/(.*)/\1.py/g;
```

The first time it searches for a match, it matches `substr($_,0,3)`, then `/g` causes it to check for another match starting at pos 3 or later.

The second time it searches for a match, it matches `substr($_,3,0)`, then `/g` causes it to check for another match starting at pos 3 or later.

The third time it searches for a match, it matches `substr($_,3,0)`. However, the engine refuses to match the same substring (defined as having the same starting position and the same length) twice, so it fails.

Solutions:

```
s/(.*)/\1.py/;    # Poor
s/^(.*)/\1.py/g;  # Poor
s/^(.*)/\1.py/;   # Ok
s/$/.py/;         # Better
$_ .= '.py';      # Best if -l was present
```

Comment: I was under the impression `.*` was greedy though, and should surely match the whole string... Or is it that after it has matched the whole string it will then match nothing at the end of the string?

Comment: It is greedy. It did match the whole string. Yes, that's exactly what I said.